# Locally connectedness: definition

Tags: general-topology, definition, connectedness, locally-connected

I have found two different definitions of locally connectedness:

(1) A topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is called ``locally connect at $x\in X$'', if every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains an open and connected neighbourhood $V$ of $x$.

(2) A topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is called ``locally connect at $x\in X$'', if every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains a connected neighbourhood $V$ of $x$.

So they differ only by the word ``open''. Are this two definition equivalent? If not, which one is the more standard one?

A neighbourhood of $x$ is defined as a set, which contains an open set, which contains $x$. So a neighbourhood is not necessarely open. That from definition (1) follows that (2) is fulfilled is obvious...but what is with the other way round?

Comment: If these are from different authors, one probably uses "neighborhood of $x$" to mean "a set containing $x$" and the other to mean "an open set containing $x$." The latter is probably more common.

Comment: @ElliotG I have also seen "neighborhood of $x$" mean "set that contains an open set that contains $x$". I actually think that that's more common than your first definition.

Comment: As alwys, it will help us to help you if you give links or references, when you ask this kind of question: we can't guess the contexts in which these definitions appear.

Comment: A neighbourhood of $x$ is defined as a set, which contains an open set, which contains $x$, as in every topological textbook

Answer (score 2):

The definitions are  not equivalent.  If there's a connected neighborhood, there's not necessarily a connected open set containing $x$ in the neighborhood.  See "broom space".  The second definition is known as *weak* local connectedness.

Comment: You need to show that a point that has no open connected neighbourhood has no connected neighbourhood at all. Definition (2) does not give an an open connected neighbourhood for free.

Comment: But why are they equivalent? A neighbourhood of $x$ is defined as a set, which contains an open set, which contains $x$. That definition (1) implies (2) is obvious....but is the other way round true in general? I mean, if a neighbourhood of $x$ is connected and closed, there is not necessarely a open AND connectes subset right?

Comment: I guess that was @RobArthan's point.  It appears I have missed a subtlety.

Comment: Sure. It may be worth pointing out the weak local connectedness everywhere is equivalent to local connectedness everywhere (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space), so the difference between the two notions of connectedness at a point is quite specialised.